# How can I handle SQLITE_CANTOPEN?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I use SQLite with Node.js. If an SQLITE_CANTOPEN error occurs, I want to feedback a message to the user like "Please contact your system administrator.", but I cannot do so because an uncaughtException event will occur if SQLITE_CANTOPEN occurs actually.

How can I return to the caller after an SQLITE_CANTOPEN occurs?

```js
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const db = new sqlite3.Database('./sample.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY, err => {
    // Comes here when we run db.all() below.
    if (err) {
        // If opening sample.db fails, SQLITE_CANTOPEN is set to err here,
        // and below raise uncaughtException event.
        throw err;
    }
});

const promise = new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
        db.all('SELECT userId, userName From user;', (err, rows) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(rows);
        });
    }
);

promise.then(value => {
    // Perform the normal process.
}, err => {
    // SQLITE_CANTOPEN can't catch here.
    return 'Please contact your system administrator.';
});
```

Comment: NIT: Promises don’t “return” to the caller - rather, they are chains of “what to do next”. In the “success” case, continue to use the DB. The the “fail” case, report the error (and don’t attempt further DB access). This is handled via standard “then” chaining of the promise to open the DB.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+promise+error+chaining

Answer (score 1):

I solved. By wrapping "new sqlite3.Database()" in a Promise, I was able to handle SQL_CANTOPEN before the SQL is executed.

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const openDBPromise = new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
        const db = new sqlite3.Database('./sample.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY, err => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(db);
        });
    }
);

let db;
try {
  db = await openDBPromise;
} catch (err) {
  // SQLITE_CANTOPEN can handle here!
  return 'Please contact your system administrator.';
}

// Perform the normal process.
```